# TB Mega Menu Problem Reordering Columns

Tags: routes

I have a site using tb mega menu. The only problem I have with it is it will not allow me to place a column to the left of another column. It just groups the two with the one I want to move always at the bottom. This wouldn't be much a problem if I could reorder the structure menu and see it affected on tb mega menu pages. The only solution I found was deleting the database row of that menu and starting over.

Comment: First Question and it's down voted.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem correctly. This video may possibly help, skip to 4:40 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnuhbFwsJ3M&feature=kp

Comment: It's when you have more than one submenu in a dropdown. the submenu to right positioned will never go to left. and it's when using the group option for both sub menus.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport, and should be posted in issue queue, not here.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was due to weights I had on the menu links as well as the actual ordering in the menu admin page. I re-ordered them in the normal menu settings page, and then I was able to order them properly in the TB Mega Menu settings page.